# Proportionality of inter-dependent variables.

Tags: analysis

I'm a physician with a special interest in cardiovascular physiology. I am trying to comprehend the relationship between flow (cardiac output, Q), pressure (mean arterial pressure, P) and resistance (total peripheral resistance, R).

Their relationship is often cited as Q = P/R.

Given  (i) Q is directly proportional to P and inversely proportional to R.
(ii) P is directly proportional to Q and directly proportional to R.
(iii) R is independent to changes of Q or P.

In this situation, if R is doubled, how would that effect Q and P?

My thought process -
(A) If we ignore its effect on Q, P would double when R is doubled.
(B) If we ignore its effect on P, Q would be halved if R is doubled.
(C) If we consider its effects on both Q and P, the results would be somewhere between situation A and situation B. My intuition says P would increase by 50% and Q would decrease by 50% (exactly in the middle of situation A and B). Is this mathematically accurate? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Does the body maintain cardiac output or arterial pressure? If the heart adapts its rhythm to maintain a constant output then the arterial pressure must increase to account for the increase in resistance.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Notwithstanding the physiological responses, I'm just trying to understand how these relationships work mathematically. So if there are no "adaptations", how would the end result look like if R is doubled?

Comment: Mathematically, $R=\frac{P}{Q}$. There are an infinite number of ways $P$ and $Q$ can change to account for the fact that $R$ has doubled. For example, if $R=r$, $P=p$, $Q=q$ and $R=\frac{P}{Q}$ then when $R$ changes from $r$ to $2r$, $P=2kp$ and $Q=kq$ for any $k$ will maintain the ratio.